# How to set dark mode appearance to auto in terminal

Tags: macos, catalina, dark-mode

[image: general]

I found the way to set dark mode:

```
defaults write -g NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool true
```

But have no idea set it to Auto with `defaults write`.

It could also be great to explain how you discovered this.

Thank you!

Comment: What does Auto mean when used with dark mode- light mode?

Comment: @jmh it means set dark mode on sunset and set light mode on sunrise.

Comment: Ok, thanks! i should have guessed that. Sorry!

Comment: You basically want to revert setting your computer to permanent dark mode, right? Googled your script and found a related question, is the first comment on this answer what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563021/4722345 possibly `defaults delete -g NSRequires...`

Comment: @JBallin Thank you and I want to set the light/dark mode to **auto**, it depends on sunrise/sunset. MacOS Catalina has provided this feature(the image in the question), I want to set it from terminal with a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit 2021**
Just do the change between a b.

```
defaults read > a
defaults read > b
diff a b
```

---

**The answer is in step 7 and step 9.**

1. Setup git in the `~/Library/Preferences/` folder to determine the incoming changes.

   ```bsh
   cd ~/Library/Preferences/
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "init commit"
   ```
2. Open **System Preferences** -> **General**, change **Appearance** from **Light** to **Auto**. I found only `.GlobalPreferences.plist` has been changed.
3. Open `.GlobalPreferences.plist` in [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with [Binary Plist](https://github.com/dnicolson/binary-plist) plugin to view plist file as xml syntax.
4. Copy the `.GlobalPreferences.plist` file content in VSCode and paste to [Diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/) **Original Text**.
5. Change **Appearance** from **Auto** to **Light**.
6. Copy the `.GlobalPreferences.plist` file content in VSCode and paste to [Diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/) **Changed Text**. I found the diff content is:

   ```xml
   <key>AppleInterfaceStyleSwitchesAutomatically</key>
   <true/>
   ```
7. Run the `defaults write` command to set the **Appearance** to **Auto**

   ```bsh
   defaults write -g AppleInterfaceStyleSwitchesAutomatically -bool true
   ```
8. Remove the `.git` in `~/Library/Preferences/`
9. Log out and log in the computer.
10. Open **System Preferences** -> **General**. You'll see the **Appearance** is set to **Auto**.

Comment: git diff can be used for untracked files too. So you just need to make copies & use `git diff <path to file 1> <path to file 2>`

Comment: @ankii Thank you! I didn't know that and I tried `git diff *` but it didn't show the expecting content, maybe because of the plist is binary file? I also found that VSCode didn't highlight the changes. Please correct me if I was wrong. ;)

Comment: right, it's due to the files being binary. But ordinarily, text files can be compared like that. So I used Xcode to export text/ XML file. Then I was able to compare them easily. If you're feeling courageous, use hexdump to compare them ;) https://superuser.com/questions/125376/how-do-i-compare-binary-files-in-linux  http://rawsyntax.com/blog/comparing-plist-files-on-osx/