# Mojave disable download bouncing in dock? (no-bouncing doesn't work)

Tags: mojave, dock, defaults

I'm trying to disable all bouncing on the dock and have used in past versions of MacOS

```
$ defaults write com.apple.dock no-bouncing -bool TRUE
$ killall Dock
```

however this is not stopping the newly downloaded icons from continuing to bounce.  I tried looking at the defaults read for com.apple.dock, with no avail.  Does anyone know what setting will completely disable all the annoying bouncing?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the App start bounce in System Preferences > Dock > Animate opening Applications.

If you want to check preferences file for the changes it makes, see this answer for details on how to check that. Comments has an easier way too.

- [How to set dark mode appearance to auto in terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391686/how-to-set-dark-mode-appearance-to-auto-in-terminal/391814#391814)

Comment: Disabling 'Apps start' bouncing will not disable download bouncing.  Further although the linked answer is great for finding .plist changes using a diff method, it is limited as it does not help find a hidden or non-preference checkbox item.  It might help if I use a heuristic method, but I lack the tools to verify changes without potentially breaking the OS.  Further suggestions/resources?